# How to run lengthy task from a web request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a website application and one page allows the user to update the database in a way that could potentially take several minutes.

In the interest of avoiding time outs and keeping the site responsive, how can I run a lengthy task like this?

I found the article [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), but it' talking about timers and stuff and I don't see how that would apply to my case.

Can anyone point me to a modern example that shows how to run a lengthy from a web request?

*Note that it would be nice to be able to tell the user when the task is complete, but that may not be totally necessary.*

*Also note, the actually work will be done by calling a RESTful API. So providing progress updates via AJAX is not an option.*

Comment: Well, the fact of a ajax call, or a rest call? Really very much the same thing. in both cases, unless the web method, or the rest end point (really much the same thing) either has some means to save/store/have some value that shows how far the process has gone, or it has not, then in both cases, all you can really do is show a "indeterminate" spinner anyway.  So, it not clear if you ok with some spinner (say animated gif) in both cases? If  you are, then the solution will be much the same in both cases. (the client side js makes the rest or ajax call - and during that time display a spinner)

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: The point is, my website has no way to say what percent the task is finished. Also, the API has a separate database so they can't communicate view data in the database either.

Comment: Ok, it was just a question. So no "value" represents how far done. Ok, so your answer is no then you don't have a "value" of progress. So, then a indeterminate progress bar or animated gif would be your only reasonable choice here.  So, what code calls the rest api, and how is that code called? In other words, while rest call is waiting,  that same code that makes the rest call should also be able to display the wait spinner. In fact, use a client side js button, and it can display the animated gif, and then call whatever code for rest call. Upon return, page refresh and gif will hide.

Comment: You might want to look into WebSockets. That way you can make an API call that fires off a task, and return immediately, and then WebSockets can update the front-end on that status. You can also look into "polling" or "Fire and Forget".

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of function what I do will like below

1. Call update database API and the API will run update script asynchronized.
2. Before run update script asynchronized, insert a status record to database, redis or file which you prefer for record updating task status.
3. The API return processing status to front-end
4. After updating task change the status to success
5. Before the status is success, we show a loading for user
6. You can send a notify to user after task success